# Ajax not working for nested loop

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

In sizes.rb controller

```
def show
   @size = Size.find(params[:id])
end
```

show.html.erb

```
    <% @sizes.each do |size| %>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
         <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>Custom Size Name</th>
          </tr>
         </thead>
         <% size.custom_sizes.each do |custom_size| %>
           <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td>
                 <%= link_to "Portrait",portrait_indesign_path(size.id,:id1=>custom_size.id,:portrait=>"portrait"),:remote=>true,:id=>"portrait1", :class => "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>  |
                 <%= link_to "Landscape",portrait_indesign_path(size.id,:id1=>custom_size.id,:portrait=>"landscape"),:remote=>true,:id=>"portrait2",:class => "btn btn-default btn-xs"%>
               </td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         <% end%>
      </table>
      <div id="modal-box" style="display:none;"></div>
    </div>
  <% end%>
```

In sizes.rb controller

```
def portrait_indesign
    custom_size=CustomSize.find(params[:id1])
    size=Size.find(params[:id])
    @size1=size.no_of_columns        
    respond_to do |format|
      if params[:portrait] == "portrait"
        format.js {render :action => "portrait_indesign"}
      elsif params[:portrait] == "landscape"
        format.js {render :action => "landscape_indesign"}
      end
    end
  end
```

In portrait_indesign.js

```
$("#modal-box").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "sizes/portrait_indesign") %>");
```

In _portrait_indesign.html.erb

```
 <html>
      <body>
        <a id="download_file" href="."><button type="submit" value="Ok" id="ok" class = "btn btn-default btn-xs">Download Portrait Template - <%= @sizeName%></button></a>  
      </body>
    </html>
    <script>
      '<%=@size1%>'
      var txt = document.getElementById('download_file');      
      document.getElementById("download_file").setAttribute("href", "");
      txt.value ='var myDocument = app.documents.add();pageHeight = "800pt";pageWidth = "600pt";myDocument.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.points;myDocument.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.points;myDocument.viewPreferences.rulerOrigin = RulerOrigin.pageOrigin;var myMasterSpread = myDocument.masterSpreads.item(0); var myMarginPreferences = myMasterSpread.pages.item(0).marginPreferences;myMarginPreferences.columnCount = '+'<%=@size1%>'+';myMarginPreferences.columnGutter = 14;';
document.getElementById('download_file').onclick = function(code) {            document.getElementById("download_file").setAttribute("download", '<%=@sizeName%>'+"_portrait.jsx");
            this.href = 'data:text/x-csrc;charset=utf-8,'
              + encodeURIComponent(txt.value);
              window.location.reload(true);
        };
</script>
```

Like portrait_indesign.js and _portrait_indesign.html.erb I wrote landscape.
[Portrait and Landscape buttons are present in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1F6V.png)

When I am clicked on **Portrait** button then **Download button** will come where I can download respective code.Before clicking on **Download button** If I clicked on  **Landscape** button but **Landscape download button** didn't came. Still it is in portrait download button only. After refreshing page It is working properly.
[portrait and landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhRip.jpg)